# Application definded or object define error when calling Err.Raise in vb6-Closed

Tags: error-handling, vb6

In my vb application when an error occur and I want to raise it using err.raise the error message is totally different from what I put in it description and it said failed in the same line of the Err.Raise function, after searching the error that I did mentioned above no useful information could anyone check where I'm doing wrong

```
Public Sub ErrorHandler()
        '<EhHeader>
        On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
        '</EhHeader>

        Dim sSysMsg As String
100     sProcedureName = "[" & CONST_CLASS_NAME & "." & sProcedureName & "] "

102     If RaiseSystemError Then
104         Err.Raise CONST_CLASS_ERROR, , sErrorMessage & vbCrLf & sProcedureName
        Else
106         If Err <> 0 Then
108             sSysMsg = "[" & Error$(Err) & "] " & vbCrLf
            End If
110         sErrorMessage = sErrorMessage & vbCrLf & sSysMsg & sProcedureName
        End If

112     sProcedureName = ""
114     bMethodFailed = True
116     Err = 0

        '<EhFooter>
        PROC_EXIT:
        Exit Sub
        PROC_ERR:
        If modErr.iHandleError(Err, Erl(), "cWtSvr.ErrorHandler") = vbRetry Then Resume
        Resume Next
        '</EhFooter>
End Sub
```

the error point to line 104

> "Error N0" 4444, Application-defined or object error occured in function name of exe.name of the class.ErrorHandler at line 104"

Note that Error N0:4444 is my own custom error while the rest of the error is not what I need to output so not sure what is going one

Many thanks

Comment: Set a break point on line 104 and step through the code. You'll see the line that causes the error and should be able to determine the cause.

Comment: I did step Through it, It raise the right error that I need but when I do make the file and run the exe an error saying "Error N0" 4444, Application-defined or object error occured in function <name of exe>.<name of the class>.ErrorHandler at line 104". Note the error number 4444 is my custom error that I did pass to the Err.Raise the reset is not my error description

Comment: You are not showing the declaration of your error description, or where and how you are setting it so we can only guess about that.

Comment: Sorry I found my problem, Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out what was the cause previously I wasn't able to step in the code of the Err.Raise but after doing some reading I was able to change the VB6 IDE Configuration about how to step in the raised error and I find out the issue it is in the class code. 
Many Thanks for trying to help out

Comment: So to confirm, the error was being picked up and reset by an error procedure elsewhere?